# Usage of the phrasal verb "look at" when there's actually nothing to see in this particular example

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I wonder whether the usage of the phrasal verb "look at" is possible and OK when there's actually nothing to see(by eyes) in this case.

> Now let's move on and **look at** the structure of [skeletal muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_muscle).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: yes, you can use **look at** without implying the use of your eyes.

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look-at-sth), these meanings do not imply that use

> [THINK] to think about a subject carefully so that you can make a decision about it
>
> [HAVE OPINION] 
>   to consider something in a particular way

Notice that I've omitted the word "see" because it also may imply in some contexts that you don't need your eyes to see something.

Some examples from the [same dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/see):

> [UNDERSTAND] to understand, know, or realize
>
> [MEET] to meet or visit someone, or to visit a place
>    to have a romantic relationship with someone

With that said, I think that your example implies the use of the eyes generally.
You have to read that article of the wikipedia to know more about the skeletal muscle. That article or a book or a schema or whatever is being pointed by the teacher giving the lesson.